# Facebook API - No value for birthday

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to get the birthday from the users, but I am receiving this error:

> 06-01 17:43:05.683: W/System.err(15173): org.json.JSONException: No
>   value for birthday

I tried to log in into my App using two accounts, and I only could get the birthday from the first one.

My code:

```
loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
            List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email", "user_birthday");
            loginButton.setReadPermissions(permissionNeeds);

            loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)
                {
                    System.out.println("onSuccess");
                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest
                            (loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback()
                            {


                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
                                        GraphResponse response) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                     // Application code
                                    Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                                    //System.out.println("Check: " + response.toString());
                                    try
                                    { 
                                        String id = object.getString("id");
                                        String name = object.getString("name");
                                        String email = object.getString("email");
                                        String gender = object.getString("gender");
                                        String birthday = object.getString("birthday");
                                        String getgender = "";

                                        if(getgender.equals("male")){
                                          getgender = "2";
                                        }else{
                                          getgender = "1";
                                        }

                                        facebookLogin(email, name, getgender);

                                    Log.e("", birthday);
                                    }
                                    catch (JSONException e)
                                    { 
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    } 
                                }
                            });
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();

                    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();
                }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that the second user has made this info private?

Comment: unfortunately thats not the solution, but thanks btw

Comment: Did the user get _asked_ for the permission during login?

Comment: Is your app still in development mode? and if not, did you get the `user_birthday` permission approved? if not, then non-app admins/developers/testers won't get notified about this permission. Moreover, have you tried this on Graph API Explorer? or fbrell.com? did you get the same results?

Comment: im facing the same problem any answer or suggestion ???

Comment: I first checked if the birthday is null or not, because the user can put his informations private, and I redirected the users without a birthday value to a new activity that gives the opportunity to change the birth day.

Comment: You can insert a default birthday for these users too

Answer (score 0):

This is basically because you need to ask Facebook to review for permission to get users b'day . You have access to your b'date but not of others.

refer this link

developer.facebook.com

on you facebook dashboard go to items in review and then from there add permissions and facebook verification will start after that you will be able to get users b'date
screenshot][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEL7c.png)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have to check json contains value or not.

```
 JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    if(jObj.has("birthday"){
    birthday = jObj.getString("birthday");
    }
```